# how to export Export Multiple tables data in single with different sheet using Kendo-vue

Tags: javascript, export, kendo-grid

If you want to export multiple grid table data in single file and each table data set in different sheet then you can export by this method. It's simple and easy way.

Answer (score 0):

Import these packages;

import {
saveExcel,
workbookOptions,
toDataURL,
} from "@progress/kendo-vue-excel-export";

import { saveAs } from "@progress/kendo-file-saver";

Suppose you click on button and event name **allTableDataExport** then

```
allTableDataExport(data) {
  console.log("first sheet table data pass here", data);
  this.customSaveExcel({
    data: data.data,
    fileName: "myFile",
    columns: data.columns,
  });
},
customSaveExcel: function(exportOptions) {
  const saveFn = (dataURL) => {
    saveAs(dataURL, exportOptions.fileName);
  };
  const firstTable = workbookOptions(exportOptions);
  const secondTable = workbookOptions({
    data: this.second_table_data,
    fileName: "myFile",
    columns: this.second_table_column,
  });
  const thirdTable = workbookOptions({
    data: this.third_table_data,
    fileName: "myFile",
    columns: this.third_table_column,
  });
  const fourthTable = workbookOptions({
    data: this.forth_table_data,
    fileName: "myFile",
    columns: this.forth_table_data,
  });
  console.log("options", firstTable);
  firstTable.sheets.push(secondTable.sheets[0]);
  firstTable.sheets.push(thirdTable.sheets[0]);
  firstTable.sheets.push(fourthTable.sheets[0]);
  toDataURL(firstTable).then(saveFn);
},
```